# Information gain obtained by updating knowledge on "possible values" of a R.V

Tags: entropy, information-theory, kullback-leibler

Let's assume that one does not know all possible values of a random variable $X$. He/she only knows that $X$ can be $1$ with probability $p(1)$ (and so $P(X \ne 1) = 1 - p(1))$, but does not know what other candidates are there. Now he/she get some "information" on $X$, so knows that all possible values are $1$, $2$, and $3$ each with probability $p'(1)$, $p'(2)$, and $p'(3)$. Are there any widely used measure to quantify the gained information? If all possible values were already known, I can use the KL divergence to quantify the information gain by updating a prior to a posterior. Otherwise how can I quantify it?